# Custom AuthorizeAttribute Not Called by MVC Framework

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api, authorize-attribute

I've been all over the internet trying to find out why my custom AuthorizeAttribute does not work in my MVC WebApi. I've seen people asking about this kind of thing on SO but nothing has helped me solve my problem yet:

```
 [AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Method, AllowMultiple = false, 
                 Inherited = false)]
    public sealed class CustomAuthorization : AuthorizeAttribute
    {

        //...

         protected override bool AuthorizeCore(HttpContextBase httpContext)
        { 
           // custom auth logic, returns true if authorized, false otherwise
        }
    }
```

I am extending from `System.Web.Mvc` as opposed to `System.Web.Http`. However, my `AuthorizeCore(HttpContextBase httpContext)` is never called.

I have a constructor in my `CustomAuthorization` class that takes a `params string[]` which are the names of my custom permissions required for a particular action, eg:

```
[CustomAuthorization("Some Permission")]
[System.Web.Http.HttpGet]
public CustomResponse SomeAction()
{
   //...
}
```

What I am hoping to achieve is to have my authorization code fired whenever a request is made to an action decorated with the `[CustomAuthorization]` attribute. I also want to be able to return a more descriptive auth failed message if the authorization fails. Not just:

```
{"Message":"Authorization has been denied for this request."}
```

I believe this involves overriding `HandleUnauthorizedRequest` but how can I do this to provide my own object that a JSON response will serialize?

To summarize, my authorization code is never called by the framework even if I decorate the actions with my `[CustomAuthorization]` attribute. It just goes straight to executing the code inside the action.

Secondly, how can I implement the unauthorized responses to serialize a custom JSON object?

Thanks for your help in advance, it is much appreciated!

Comment: Basing my comments on how I implemented a custom authorization attribute... For started, I think you want to override OnAuthorization, not AuthorizeCore. Also, I'm not sure you need to have your class sealed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ok I eventually solved it and this is how:

```
public override void OnAuthorization(HttpActionContext actionContext) {

    ....

    if (!authorized) {

       actionContext.Response =    
                  actionContext.Request.CreateResponse(
                                   HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized, 
                                   new  Dictionary<string, string> { 
                                                { "hello", "world" } 
                                   }
                  );

    }
```

}

Which produces the result:

```
{"hello":"world"}
```

The Dictionary object is arbitrary, it just demonstrates that a type will be serialized to the Response successfully.

If you don't set the `actionContext.Response` then the Request will continue to the target action - ie. it is deemed authorized by this filter.

Hope that helps others in this position.

Comment: It was a relief to find the solution so simple! Thanks for your efforts, much appreciated. Glad it all works now!